# How to check if the server is reachable and running?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my IOS application I have a sign in method that sends to the java server the username and password.
the problem is that if the server is offline, the application freezes. And when the server is back on, the application continues. 
So is there an Exception Handling that i should place for the application to check if the server is online before sending the data?

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"XXXXX", 678, &readStream,
                                   &writeStream);
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
}
 -(void) connection{
[self initNetworkCommunication];
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open]; 
[outputStream open];

   }

////// thats how I'm sending the username and password 

 NSString *username= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",UsernameTextField.text];
NSString *password=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",PasswordTextField.text];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",username,password);

NSData *usernamedata = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[username dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSData *passworddata = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[usernamedata bytes] maxLength:[usernamedata length]];
[outputStream write:[passworddata bytes] maxLength:[passworddata length]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest you take a look at [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It solves all your problems with networking, including asynchronous connections using blocks.

*I am assuming your application freezes, because your network connection is running on the same thread as UI and the thread is waiting for the connection to timeout.*

I would recommend you take a look at AFNetworking examples. This is the code you need for Reachability with `AFNetworking`:

```
if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable)
{
    ...
}
```